# Getting the count of entries in entitySet in OData using java

Tags: java, rest, odata, httpconnection, olingo

The following link returns the number of entries in the Customers entity Set http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers/$count

How to get this number using java?

```
 URL url = new URL("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers/$count");
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestMethod("GET")
```

What to code after this to get the count of entries as integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the data from `HttpURLConnection` inputstream like

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    conn.getInputStream()));
        String count;
        while ((count = in.readLine()) != null) 
            //this will print the count in count variable
            System.out.println(count);
        in.close();
    }
```

Note : You have to do it after you write the request to the outputstream of the `HttpURLConnection`. This clearly means that you write the request data to the connection's output stream and read the response data from the connection's input stream

Comment: Why can not we use getContent() method here ?